# For loop not working in makefile: "i was unexpected at this time"

Tags: windows, makefile

I have a very simple makefile:

```
all:
    @for i in 1 2 3;\
    do \
        echo "i: $$i";\
    done
```

And yet when I run this, I got a "i was unexpected at this time" error.

Any idea why this is the case?

**I am running on Windows XP. What's the Windows equivalent for the above script?**

Comment: Runs fine with GNU Make 3.81 on Linux. Which Make are you using?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you are running on Windows (likely, because of [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2018955/foreach-loop-not-working-in-makefile-the-system-cannot-find-the-file-specified)) , the commands you write must be valid Windows commands. I mean commands that you could run in the Windows shell `cmd.exe`.

Here, the commands you try to run are valid UNIX commands for a bash shell. They are not for the Windows shell.

Comment: Thanks! I should have thought of that

Answer (score 0):

Seems to work fine for me:

```
[01:30:10][/tmp]$ make
i: 1
i: 2
i: 3
[01:30:26][/tmp]$ cat Makefile
all:
        @for i in 1 2 3;\
        do \
        echo "i: $$i";\
        done
```

Comment: because you are not running on windows