# Makefile For Loop on Windows

Tags: windows, makefile

This is a similar question to the one I [ask here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019290/for-loop-not-working-in-makefile-i-was-unexpected-at-this-time). I am running on Windows XP.

I am trying to get for loop to work on Windows. Following the suggestion that [I have to make sure that the command are valid cmd command](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2019290/for-loop-not-working-in-makefile-i-was-unexpected-at-this-time/2019361#2019361), I constructed a valid for loop batch command:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%G IN ("deposit,$4500,123.4,12-AUG-09") ^
DO ^
echo Date paid %%G ^
```

And put it in a Makefile. This is the content of the makefile:

```
all:
    @echo off
    FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%G IN ("deposit,$4500,123.4,12-AUG-09") ^
    DO ^
    echo Date paid %%G ^
```

But still, I got an error:

> FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%G IN
>   ("deposit,500,123.4,12-AUG-09") ^
>   make: *** [all] Error 255

Any idea how to fix this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I've found the answer, this is the correct syntax that runs in Makefile Windows:

```
all:
    @echo off
    FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%G IN ("deposit,$4500,123.4,12-AUG-09") \
    DO   \
    echo Date paid %%G echo 123
```

Answer (score 1):

I've found that by using && you can do multiple commands inside the for loop like so:

```
    for %%i in ($(SOMETHING)) do echo %%i 1 && echo %%i 2 && echo %%i 3
```

This will printout something like:

```
1 1
2 2
3 3
```

Answer (score 0):

your split is wrong, don't use ^. Do as following:

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%G IN ("deposit,$4500,123.4,12-AUG-09") DO  (
    echo Date paid %%G
    rem you can put as many lines as you want here, inside of braces
    echo 123
)
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion, but it outputed the exact string `For /F "" .... echo 123)`, not the result.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can call your batch command file from the Makefile?

```
all:
    MyBatch.bat "deposit,$$4500,123.4,12-AUG-09"
```

With MyBatch.bat as follows.

```
@echo off
FOR /F "tokens=4 delims=," %%G IN ("%1") ^
DO ^
echo Date paid %%G ^
```

Beware the $ in the Makefile thought. $ is the escape characher and have to be doubled to get one real $ in strings.

Comment: Thanks, but I don't think I want to call batch file from my makefile. I would prefer a real makefile windows syntax.